# window.open and sending form data not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to open new window and send form data
with **javascript** and **jquery-1.8.3**. But, It's not woriking.

This is source code.

```
<a href="#" onclick="printPage()">Print this</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printPage(){

        var form = $("<form method='post' action='/common/print.jsp' target='printWindow'></form>");
        var input = $("<input type='hidden' name='view'/>");
        input.val($("#ctn").html());
        form.append(input);
        var printWindow = window.open(form.attr("action"), "printWindow", "width=700px,height=800px");
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

window was opened. But  `request.getParameter("name")` is null.

Here is `/common/print.jsp` page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>
<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
<div id="ctn">
<%
    out.print(request.getParameter("view"));
%>
</div>
```

What's the problem in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you faking an ajax call ;-)

Better you do something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="printPage()">Print this</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function printPage(){

    $.post('/common/print.jsp', {view:$("#ctn").html()}).success(function(response){
        var oWindow = window.open('', "printWindow", "width=700px,height=800px");
        oWindow.document.write(response);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's really helpful for me.

Comment: Can I ask more question? I committed your code in my project, and added `oWindow.print();` after `oWindow.document.write(response);` FF, Chrome working, but IE9 does not working. Would you mind giving a hint for me again please?

Comment: Yes of course. Try to add a script to your rerver response or manually behind response var. eg: oWindow.document.write(response+'<script>window.print();</script>');