# Tryied window.open with Ajax, window.print not working (IE9)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to open new window and send form data with javascript and jquery-1.8.3.

With Bernhard's help I succeeded to call a new window with page for print.

(Thank you so much Bernhard. [window.open and sending form data not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226470/window-open-and-sending-form-data-not-working))

But, `window.print()` function does not working in IE9! (FF, Chorme do well)

I refreshed the page, then IE9 calls `window.print()`

Here is source code.

```
<a href="#" onclick="printPage()">Print this</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function printPage(){

    $.post('/common/print.jsp', {view:$("#ctn").html()}).success(function(response){
        var oWindow = window.open('', "printWindow", "width=700px,height=800px");
        oWindow.document.write(response);
        oWindow.print(); // I added this line. But IE9 not working.
    });
}
</script>
```

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    $.post('/common/print.jsp', {view:$("#ctn").html()}).success(function(response){
        var oWindow = window.open('', "printWindow", "width=700px,height=800px");
        oWindow.document.write(response);
        oWindow.document.close();
        oWindow.focus();
        oWindow.print(); // I added this line. But IE9 not working.
    });
```

checkout this:

`Using HTTP Headers to Force Standards View in Internet Explorer 8 and Above`

You can also use meta tags to force standards mode. The `X-UA-Compatible meta tag` tells Internet Explorer what view mode to use or emulate.

`By setting this meta tag, you tell IE to use standards mode even if there are comments or an XML declaration above the DOCTYPE.` You `determine what version of Internet Explorer can best view the page`, and then set the meta tags to define that version.

```
IE 7:

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=7"> 

IE 8:

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8"> 

IE 9:

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9">
```

> If a customer comes to a page with a view mode higher than it supports
>   (e.g. an IE 7 browser viewing a page asking for IE8 view mode), it
>   will ignore the tag and render the page the the mode it would have
>   without the tag.

More info find here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/internetexplorer/qt/force-compatibility-view-in-ie.htm

Comment: Is there forcing to compability view on?

Comment: checkout this one: http://webdesign.about.com/od/internetexplorer/qt/force-compatibility-view-in-ie.htm

Comment: I failed to solve(I tryied another routine), but your answer was very help for me. Thank you Jai.